# Rcpp override summary method for custom class

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpp11

Suppose I have the following function:

```
List foo(List x) 
{
   x.attr("class") = "myOwnClass";
   return(x);
}
```

I whant to override R **summary** method for **foo** function output. However the following R-style approach does not work:

```
List summary.myOwnClass(List x) 
{
   return(x)
}
```

During compilation I have a error which says that "expected initializer before '.' token".

Please help me to understand how to implement **summary** function **override** within **Rcpp** framework for my **customly defined class**.

Will be very greatfull for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like this is likely a duplicate, but my initial search didn't pull one up. I add a quick answer for now, but if I later find one I'll delete this answer and propose a duplicate.

The way to solve this issue is to use the `export` tag to specify the function's R side name as `summary.myOwnClass` while using something else for the C++ side name; you can't have dots in the middle of a C++ function name (think about, e.g., how member functions are called -- it would be unworkable). So, we do the following

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List foo(List x)
{
    x.attr("class") = "myOwnClass";
    return(x);
}

// [[Rcpp::export(summary.myOwnClass)]]
List summary(List x)
{
    return(x);
}

/*** R
l <- foo(1:3)
summary(l)
*/
```

Then we get the output we expect

```
> l <- foo(1:3)

> summary(l)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

attr(,"class")
[1] "myOwnClass"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this elegant solution!

Comment: @Bogdan Glad it helped! I would highly recommend reading all the vignettes available for Rcpp (you can see them at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html). For example, this issue is discussed in section 1.6 of the Rcpp Attributes vignette. It may seem like a lot of reading, but you'll save yourself a lot of issues in the future

Comment: thank you for suggestion, I will carefully look throught it!